# Firebase Dropdown menu shows hint text as dropdown value (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My dropdown menu makes use of Firebase to populate the data. Initially the `setState` callback did not make any changes to the `onChanged` property. I finally got this to change by modifying the hint text - it works now, but definitely not as it should or as I want it to work.

My code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('field_management')
    .orderBy('block_name')
    .snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
    }
    return DropdownButton(
        items: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
                value: document['block_name'],
                child: Text(document['block_name']),
            );
            }).toList(),
        onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() => blockDropdownValue = newValue.toString());
        },
        hint: Text(blockDropdownValue),
    );
},
),
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: _"but definitely not as it should or as I want it to work"_. Well, can you please [edit] your question to explain how it _should_ work? Please elaborate on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the selected value to the `hint` property. Don't do that. Assign it to the `value` property of the `DropdownButton` widget. By doing this, you will be able to display the selected value after the `onChanged` callback.

For the hint, give it some other text.

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('field_management')
    .orderBy('block_name')
    .snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
    }
    return DropdownButton(
        items: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return DropdownMenuItem(
                value: document['block_name'],
                child: Text(document['block_name']),
            );
            }).toList(),
        onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() => blockDropdownValue = newValue.toString());
        },

        // add the below two lines
        value: blockDropdownValue,
        hint: Text('Select a value'),
    );
},
),
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. Not sure how I missed this one :-)